# input range not working in ie or edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, microsoft-edge

Has anyone else come across this issue and do you have a solution.

Using this html in ie and edge the range doesn't show.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <form method="post" action="/Tactics">
                        <table align="center" width="100%">
                            <tr><td>stuff</td><td><input type="range" min="10" max="50"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>stuff</td><td><input type="range" min="10" max="50"></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you take out the first stuff for each row in the table the input range works again.  It's fine in crome, firefox and opera.

Has anyone seen this and do you know how to fix?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that accurately represents the issue you encountered? I work on the Edge team, and we would like to see if there is something we can do to improve this experience for others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add MS fillers:

```
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
/*example */
width: 250px;height: 10px;
background: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
border-width: 6px 0;
color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
background: gray;
border-radius: 6px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
background: gray;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

This is just example but you need to focus on these:

```
    input[type=range]::-ms-track
    input[type=range]::-ms-thumb
    input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper
    input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower
```

Check the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/brenna/f4uq9edL/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=f4uq9edL)