# Range slider will not display properly in IE

Tags: css

So I am having an issue with my range slider displaying properly in IE 11. As you can see in Chrome it displays properly. Here is a comparison. What am I missing in my CSS for the IE layout? Z-index on the sliders to pull them forward throws off the layout.

[image]

Here is the range slider code

```
<div class="form-group rangeSlider-pos" style="padding-bottom:35px;">
    <p style="padding-left:20px;"><label for="min">AGE</label></p>
        <div class="rangeslider custom-select">
            <span class="range_min light left spanLeftMin"> 18 </span>
            <input class="min" name="range_1" type="range" min="18" max="60" value="18" />                                      
            <input class="max" name="range_1" type="range" min="18" max="60" value="60" />
            <span class="range_max light right spanRightMax"> 60 </span>
        <div id="ageRange"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS to display it.

```
input[type='range'] {
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
width: 250px;
margin-top: -10px;
height: 60px;
left: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
}
input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
   background: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 190px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #336699;
}
input[type='range']:nth-child(2)::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
  background: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
input[type='range']:nth-child(1)::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  z-index: 99;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
    background: transparent; 
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #336699;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* All the same stuff for IE */
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #336699;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: $range-assertive-track-bg;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #336699;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #336699;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: $range-assertive-track-bg;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #336699;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    position: relative;
    width: $range-slider-width;
    height: $range-slider-height;
    border-radius: $range-slider-border-radius;
    background-color: $toggle-handle-off-bg-color;
    box-shadow: $range-slider-box-shadow;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:9999;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb:before {
    /* what creates the colorful line on the left side of the slider */
    position: absolute;
    top: ($range-slider-height / 2) - ($range-track-height / 2);
    left: -2001px;
    width: 2000px;
    height: $range-track-height;
    background: $dark;
    content: ' ';
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb:after {
    /* create a larger (but hidden) hit area */
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    padding: 30px;
    content: ' ';
}

.rangeslider{
    color:#ccc;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.rangeslider input{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.rangeslider span{
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.rangeslider .right{
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   margin-right: -120px;
}
```

I updated my Code with the latest
Oh and here is the javascript to run it in case anybody wanted to use it.

```
//Range slider function for age range
(function() {

    function addSeperator(nStr) {
        nStr += '';
        var x = nStr.split('.');
        var x1 = x[0];
        var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
    }

    function rangeInputChangeEventHandler(e){
        var rangeGroup = $(this).attr('name'),
            minBtn = $(this).parent().children('.min'),
            maxBtn = $(this).parent().children('.max'),
            range_min = $(this).parent().children('.range_min'),
            range_max = $(this).parent().children('.range_max'),
            minVal = parseInt($(minBtn).val()),
            maxVal = parseInt($(maxBtn).val()),
            origin = $(this).context.className;

        if(origin === 'min' && minVal > maxVal-5){
            $(minBtn).val(maxVal-5);
        }
        var minVal = parseInt($(minBtn).val());
        $(range_min).html(addSeperator(minVal*1));


        if(origin === 'max' && maxVal-5 < minVal){
            $(maxBtn).val(5+ minVal);
        }
        var maxVal = parseInt($(maxBtn).val());
        $(range_max).html(addSeperator(maxVal*1));
    }

 $('input[type="range"]').on( 'input', rangeInputChangeEventHandler);

})();
```

One last question for anyone who sees this, Do you know how to get the left Button to show over top of the slider bar that is from the right side?

here is the current display now. :)

[image]

Appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: Hope it will help you, :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519215/input-range-not-working-in-ie-or-edge

Comment: Thank you @jaydeeppatel, that has helped get me closer to what I am trying to achieve. I'm still trying to get the left button to display over top of the bar but at least it is overall displaying properly. Thanks again. I will update my code for anyone else who may need it or can find the fix to overlay the left button over top of the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to missing -ms styles. Add this and you’re good to go:

```css
input[type=range] {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

// Slider line
::-ms-track {
    border: none;
    height: 2px;
}
::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: $range-assertive-track-bg;
}
::-ms-fill-upper {
     background: $range-assertive-track-bg;
}


// Bullet
::-ms-thumb {
    position: relative;
    width: $range-slider-width;
    height: $range-slider-height;
    border-radius: $range-slider-border-radius;
    background-color: $toggle-handle-off-bg-color;
    box-shadow: $range-slider-box-shadow;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    border: 0;
}

::-ms-thumb:before {
    /* what creates the colorful line on the left side of the slider */
    position: absolute;
    top: ($range-slider-height / 2) - ($range-track-height / 2);
    left: -2001px;
    width: 2000px;
    height: $range-track-height;
    background: $dark;
    content: ' ';
}

::-ms-thumb:after {
    /* create a larger (but hidden) hit area */
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    padding: 30px;
    content: ' ';
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help @PHP Geek, I updated my question and added your code, still seems to overlap on the left button though. Any ideas why? thanks again.

Comment: try this one 
 .wrapper{text-align:left;}